# Подгрузка справочников в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, delphi, плагин

Имеется справочник, который я буду получать через api. А также справочник, который хранится у меня в базе данных. Мне нужно инициировать обновление справочника в БД по справочнику извне. Для актуализации информации

Будет написан плагин, который в первую очередь должен полностью обновить справочник.
1.Каким способом я могу проверить совпадение данных и обновить только необходимые строки?
1.1. Как один из вариантов - создание временной таблицы в бд для подгрузки справочника через api и полная их проверка
1.2. Второй вариант проставить в старых записях enabled = 0 и подгрузить новые записи с enabled = 1.

2.Вторым шагом будет обновление некоторых строк раз в какое-то время. Что лучше использовать в этом случае?

Уточню, что вопрос НЕ в используемых методах api, а в том, какими наименее трудозатратными и костыльными методами обновить имеющийся справочник

Comment: *полностью обновить справочник* Если под этим подразумевается "откорректировать изменившееся, добавить отсутствующее в рабочем, удалить отсутствующее в новом" - то это не обновление, а полная замена старой версии на новую. Но вообще вопрос слишком неконкретный и скорее всего будет закрыт.

Comment: Самый простой вариант, ИМХО: считать хэш всей строки, объединив данные в полях как-нибудь и сравнивать хэши. Если при одинаковом ID записи хэши не совпадают - обновлять запись.